# SSAS 2012 How to use ParallelPeriod without Date Hierarchy?

Tags: date, ssas-2012

I found an example of how to use the Parallel Period function in my SSAS OLAP Cube here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2915/sql-server-analysis-services-period-over-period-variance-analysis/

However it assumes that you have a Date Hierarchy, which I don't. I tried using it without success. My Date Dimension only has a date attribute and a Year Month attribute (ex: 2015/01 for January 2015). It has no hierarchy nor anything else.
(Interested why? Because it just works, and a hierarchy confused my users)

I need to compare values month over month and year over year. 
This is what I could infer with the example, but it is not working:

```
IIF([Fact Date].[Date].CurrentMember.level.ordinal = 0, 
    [Measures].[Billed Amount],
    (ParallelPeriod([Fact Date].[Year Month].[Year Month],
                    1,
                    [Fact Date].[Date].CurrentMember),
     [Measures].[Billed Amount]
    )
)
```

What would be the correct syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

At the end I fixed it adding a Year attribute (ex: 2015), Month attribute (ex: 201501), and made a simple hierarchy (Year, Month, Date). It worked with the following code:

```
IIF([Fact Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.level.ordinal = 0, 
    [Measures].[Billed Amount],
    (ParallelPeriod([Fact Date].[Date Hierarchy].[Month],
                    1,
                    [Fact Date].[Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember),
     [Measures].[Billed Amount]
    )
)
```